# Why do Grub options only appear if I set 'GRUB_TERMINAL=console' on my laptop? And why isn't it set automatically?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I currently have a dual-boot setup for Win10 and Ubuntu on a Lenovo Ideapad Z580 (I5 3rd Gen).

I never touched any GRUB files on my first Ubuntu install. But then, I updated Ubuntu to 20.04 and that's when I needed to edit my `/etc/default/grub` file.

Un-commenting `GRUB_TERMINAL=console` there brought back GRUB. But now, I have to do this on every clean Ubuntu install.

I don't understand the exact reason for it. Sure, it disables graphical menu. But why do I have to enable it only for my laptop? And if it's just a necessary step, why did GRUB work automatically the first time without intervention?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you disabled Secure Boot in BIOS?

Comment: Yes...I have disabled the Secure Boot. @Terrance

Comment: Can you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1310995/edit) your question and add details about your laptop and what version of Ubuntu you are using?  There might be a chance that someone else might have stumbled across the same issue as you.  If not, you might be looking at a bug between grub and your laptop itself.

Comment: Ok. Thanks @Terrance